Python output of lines with an entry threshold greater than 1
Python output of lines with occurrence value > 1
Good afternoon, tell me how to display occurrences that have occurred more than once.
The txt file contains the following lines: 1 1 2 3
text = open("dan1.txt").read()
unique = set(text.split())

for word in unique:
    print(f'{word}: {text.count(word)}')

It turns out only to display each line and its value. I don’t understand how to output a string with a value > 1

Nothing in your set (unique) will occur more than once

You could utilise a Counter from the collections module as follows:
from collections import Counter

with open("dan1.txt") as fd:
    words = fd.read().split()
    counter = Counter(words)
    for k, v in counter.items():
        if v > 1:
            print(k)

